# Recreate spss GEE regression table in R

Tags: r

I have the (sample) dataset below:

```
round<-c( 0.125150,  0.045800, -0.955299, -0.232007,  0.120880, -0.041525,  0.290473, -0.648752,  0.113264, -0.403685)
    square<-c(-0.634753,  0.000492, -0.178591, -0.202462, -0.592054, -0.583173, -0.632375, -0.176673, -0.680557, -0.062127)
    ideo<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1)
    ex<-data.frame(round,square,ideo)
```

When I ran the GEE regression in SPSS I took this table as a result.
[image]

I used packages `gee` and `geepack` in R to run the same analysis and I took these results:

```
#gee
summary(gee(ideo ~ square + round,data = ex, id = ideo,
    corstr = "independence"))
Coefficients:
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)   1.0541     0.4099   2.572      0.1328    7.937
square        1.1811     0.8321   1.419      0.4095    2.884
round         0.7072     0.5670   1.247      0.1593    4.439

#geepack
summary(geeglm(ideo ~ square + round,data = ex, id = ideo,
            corstr = "independence"))
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)    1.054   0.133 63.00  2.1e-15 ***
square         1.181   0.410  8.32   0.0039 ** 
round          0.707   0.159 19.70  9.0e-06 ***
---
```

I would like to recreate exactly the table of SPSS(not the results as I use a subset of the original dataset)but I do not know how to achieve all these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tiny bit of `tidyverse` magic can get the same results - more or less.

Get the information from `coef(summary(geeglm()))` and compute the necessary columns:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("geepack")

coef(summary(geeglm(ideo ~ square + round,data = ex, id = ideo,
           corstr = "independence"))) %>% 
mutate(lowerWald = Estimate-1.96*Std.err, # Lower Wald CI
       upperWald=Estimate+1.96*Std.err,   # Upper Wald CI
       df=1, 
       ExpBeta = exp(Estimate)) %>%       # Transformed estimate
mutate(lWald=exp(lowerWald),              # Upper transformed
       uWald=exp(upperWald))              # Lower transformed
```

This produces the following (with the data you provided). The order and the names of the columns could be modified to suit your needs

```
  Estimate Std.err   Wald  Pr(>|W|) lowerWald upperWald df ExpBeta lWald uWald
1   1.0541  0.1328 62.997 2.109e-15    0.7938     1.314  1   2.869 2.212 3.723
2   1.1811  0.4095  8.318 3.925e-03    0.3784     1.984  1   3.258 1.460 7.270
3   0.7072  0.1593 19.704 9.042e-06    0.3949     1.019  1   2.028 1.484 2.772
```

Comment: Excellent result . I wll check some things and accept it.

Comment: Is it posiible to display the names (Intercept) -square-round in th 1st column?

Comment: Yes. Just throw a `rownames_to_column()` into the pipe string before you start mutating, ie., `...corstr = "independence"))) %>% rownames_to_column() %>% mutate(...`